# Cannot replace an elements in DOM correctly with a loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to replace a `div` elements with class `img-replace` by `img` elements in the current DOM. But the problem is, I have only the two div element with class `img-replace` while the count of an `img` elements - three.

I have the loop that must replace an elements `div` by `img` and the condition that will stop the function if `images.length > divs.length`. But it does not happen and also my loop is not working here (in browser it work with random replace result).

I'll grateful for any help.

P.S.
The count of `div` and `img` elements can be random, so we need the dynamic adaptive function.

```js
function onLoad() {
  var images = document.body.getElementsByTagName('img');
  var divs = document.body.getElementsByClassName('img-replace');

  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onload = function() {
      if (images.length > divs.length) return;
      divs[i].replaceWith(this);
    };

    images[i].onerror = function() {
      console.log("Error " + this.src);
      this.remove();
      return;
    };
  }
}

onLoad();
```

```css
.img-replace {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:114px;height:40px;font-size:32px;letter-spacing:3px" class="img-replace">
  <span style="color:#1A53F7">G</span><span style="color:#E42131">o</span><span style="color:#FEB819">o</span><span style="color:#164AF2">g</span><span style="color:#00a315">l</span><span style="color:#E42131">e</span>
</div>

<div style="width:101px;height:40px;font-size:32px" class="img-replace">
  <span style="color:purple">Yahoo!</span>
</div>

<div style="width:100;height:40px;font-size:32px;color:#006dd4;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing: 3px; font-family:Arial">bing</div>

<hr>

<img src="https://js.cx/search/google.png" width="101" height="40" alt="Google">
<img src="http://toplogos.ru/images/logo-yahoo.jpg" width="114" height="40" alt="Yahoo">
<img src="https://js.cx/search/bing.png" width="101" height="40" alt="No file (bing)">
```

Comment: Is there ever any situation where you'll have more divs than images?

Comment: Do the divs and images have the same order? Is the first/second/third/... div always the first/second/third/... image?

Comment: @Andreas the replacing order must be as an order of an elements in the DOM

Comment: If there are more images than divs, shall the spare images be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed up your declarations. The reason I did so is that it is easier to iterate over anything other than an `HTMLCollection` which is what you return from `getByClassName` and `getByTagName`. This is because they don't have any iterable(*looping*) methods attached to their prototype. Instead we will use `querySelectorAll` which returns a `NodeList`, the prototype of which allows us to use the `forEach` method. This is useful later in the script.

Furthermore we can use `Math.min` to get the lowest integer between the two lengths.

```
      var most = Math.min(images.length, divs.length);
```

This changes your declarations to look like this:

```
  var images = document.body.querySelectorAll('img');
  var divs = document.body.querySelectorAll('.img-replace');
  var most = Math.min(images.length, divs.length);
```

*FYI* you can also lay out your declaration code like this:

```
  var images = document.body.querySelectorAll('img'),
  divs = document.body.querySelectorAll('.img-replace'),
  most = Math.min(images.length, divs.length);
```

We can then loop over the arrays until `i < most` because we're guaranteed to have that many images **and** divs.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < most; i++) {
    images[i].onload = function() {
    divs[i].replaceWith(this);
    };
```

We then loop over our `images` using the `forEach` method made available by our `NodeList` and add an `onerror` function to each image.

```
    images.forEach(image => image.onerror = function() {
      console.log("Error " + this.src);
      this.remove();
      return;
    });
  }
}
```

**Note: Fat Arrows are Part of ES6 and forEach is not always implemented** - per usual IE has failed to adopt the full EcmaScript Syntax in a timely fashion, so if you're looking to use this on that platform you can simply change the code to ES5:

```
        for ( var i = 0; i < images.length; i++ ) {
          var image = image[ i ];
          image.onerror = function() {
            console.log( "Error " + this.src );
            this.remove();
            return;
          }
        } );
```

```js
function onLoad() {
  var images = document.body.querySelectorAll('img');
  var divs = document.body.querySelectorAll('.img-replace');
  var most = Math.min(images.length, divs.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < most; i++) {
    images[i].onload = function() {
    divs[i].replaceWith(this);
    };

    images.forEach(image => image.onerror = function() {
      console.log("Error " + this.src);
      this.remove();
      return;
    });
  }
}

onLoad();
```

```css
.img-replace {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:114px;height:40px;font-size:32px;letter-spacing:3px" class="img-replace">
  <span style="color:#1A53F7">G</span><span style="color:#E42131">o</span><span style="color:#FEB819">o</span><span style="color:#164AF2">g</span><span style="color:#00a315">l</span><span style="color:#E42131">e</span>
</div>

<div style="width:101px;height:40px;font-size:32px" class="img-replace">
  <span style="color:purple">Yahoo!</span>
</div>

<div style="width:100;height:40px;font-size:32px;color:#006dd4;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing: 3px; font-family:Arial">bing</div>

<hr>

<img src="https://js.cx/search/google.png" width="101" height="40" alt="Google">
<img src="http://toplogos.ru/images/logo-yahoo.jpg" width="114" height="40" alt="Yahoo">
<img src="https://js.cx/search/bing.png" width="101" height="40" alt="No file (bing)">
```

Comment: _"...which allows us to use the forEach method"_ [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility) is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: @Andreas solid point. Updated. I typically don't even bother with IE anymore so I always forget about that one.

Comment: @zfrisch thank you for a great solution! Your declaration and using the `Math.min` for right counting min of `img`'s and `div`'s elements - perfect! I want to tell you a special thank for such a glorious explanation of each step!  Cheers! :)